# LNK2019 unresolved external sumbol (cURL & Jsoncpp)

Tags: c++, libcurl, lnk2019, jsoncpp

I have been searching the internet for quite some time to find a solution to my problem and not a single one has worked. So if you can help I will be very thankful!

I have compiled the jsoncpp.lib and libcurl.lib and including them in my C++ project under the linker settings and made sure they were placed in a included directory I also including the curl.h and json.h header files in 2 respective sub directories with all the required header files for the project. every time I build my project I get 16 unresolved extern symbols all from the references to the functions in those libraries.

[Errors](https://vgy.me/1hprFE.png)

here is my precompiled header:

```
#pragma once

#include <xtl.h>
#include <xboxmath.h>

#include <curl\curl.h>
#include <json\json.h>

#include "kernel.h"
#include "tools.h"
#include "detour.h"
#include "net.h"
#include "auth.h"


#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#define memecpy memcpy
#define memecmp memcmp

#pragma comment(lib, "jsoncpp")
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl")
```

here is my auth.cpp

```
Response_Buffer userData;
namespace
    {
        std::size_t callback(
                const char* in,
                std::size_t size,
                std::size_t num,
                std::string* out)
        {
            const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
            out->append(in, totalBytes);
            return totalBytes;
        }
    }

BOOL MenuEnabled = FALSE;
char* GetCpuKey(char* cpureq) {
    BYTE step1[16];
    BYTE step2[16];
    BYTE step3[16];

    ZeroMemory(step1, 16);
    ZeroMemory(step2, 16);
    ZeroMemory(step3, 16);

    HRESULT success = HV::Peek::HvPeekBytes(0x20, step1, 0x10);
    if(success != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return NULL;

    BYTE part1[8];
    memecpy(part1, (BYTE*)HV::HvGetFuseLine(3), 8);
    BYTE part2[8];
    memecpy(part2, (BYTE*)HV::HvGetFuseLine(5), 8);
    memecpy(step2, part1, 8);
    memecpy(step2 + 8, part2, 8);

    if(memcmp(step1, step2, 16) != 0)
        return NULL;

    BYTE part3[8];
    memecpy(part3, (BYTE*)HV::HvGetFuseLine(4), 8);
    BYTE part4[8];
    memecpy(part4, (BYTE*)HV::HvGetFuseLine(6), 8);
    memecpy(step3, part3, 8);
    memcpy(step3 + 8, part4, 8);

    if(memcmp(step1, step3, 16) != 0)
        return NULL;

    if(memcmp(step2, step3, 16) != 0)
        return NULL;

    memecpy((void*)cpureq, step3, 16);

    if(memecmp((void*)cpureq, step1, 16) != 0)
        return NULL;

    std::string out = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < 0x10; i++, ++cpureq) {
      char tmp[5] = { 0 };
      sprintf(tmp, "%02X", (unsigned char)*cpureq);
      out += tmp;
     }

     return _strdup(out.c_str());
}
BOOL Authenticate()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xbonline.live/annoyance.php");
        char* post;
        sprintf(post, "cpukey=%s", GetCpuKey(NULL));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        int httpCode;
        std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
        if (httpCode == 200){
            Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::Reader jsonReader;
        if(jsonReader.parse(*httpData, jsonData)){
            memecpy(userData.name, jsonData["username"].asCString(), jsonData["username"].asString().length());
            memecpy((VOID*)userData.days, (VOID*)(jsonData["lifetime"].asBool() ? 999 : jsonData["days"].asInt()), sizeof((jsonData["lifetime"].asBool() ? 999 : jsonData["days"].asInt())));
            memecpy((VOID*)userData.status, (VOID*)jsonData["status"].asInt(), sizeof((VOID*)jsonData["status"].asInt()));
            memecpy((VOID*)userData.status, (VOID*)jsonData["status"].asInt(), sizeof((VOID*)jsonData["status"].asInt()));
            memecpy((VOID*)userData.banned, (VOID*)((jsonData["days"].asInt() == -1) ? TRUE : FALSE), sizeof(BOOL));

            curl_global_cleanup();
            return true;
        }                   
            curl_global_cleanup();
            return false;
        }
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }

}
VOID HookAuthLoop() {
    for(;;){
        if(Authenticate()) MenuEnabled = TRUE;
        else MenuEnabled = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problems, by why the `memecpy` and `memecmp` macros? Why not fix your code to be correct instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's a meme

Comment: @Persuasion It's silly and unnecessary